# goto file line number in Java

Tags: java, string, file

I want to know how to directly reach a particular line no of a text file in java.
one Method is this.

```
int line=0;
BufferedReader read=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(Filename));
while(read.readLine()!=null){
   line++;
   if(line==LIMIT) break;
}
```

But this will create a lot of String objects which wont be freed unless gc runs.
Please provide a solution that will be fast and doesn't consume a lot of memory.

**PS:I am reading from a file that has millions of lines.**

Comment: Allocating and immediately liberating millions of small objects is usually fine. There are specific optimizations for that in the VM. Of course it could be made faster but do you encounter a performance problem on that line skipping operation ?

Comment: You can always write your own endline-locating code that only reads bytes. That should be slightly faster (lots of calls to a myBufferedInputStream.read() instead of UTF-8 conversion and string-creation). Of course, at some point, you will want to convert those bytes into characters...

Comment: Have you actually run this and verified that this is causing a performance problem?

Comment: Well there will be 10-15 of such process running in a server.Want to optimize it the most so memory remains free.

Comment: @JoeDominicValluvassery: These strings will be *very* short-lived. To repeat chrylis's question: have you actually run this? Or are you just *guessing* that it's a problem? (I would suggest that a more important problem is the use of `FileReader`, which always uses the platform default encoding - I'd suggest using `InputStreamReader` and specifying the encoding explicitly.)

Comment: @chrylis:no i haven't.

Comment: @JonSkeet:but when will gc take care of this. because later on i may have to read from a file which has a billion lines.

Comment: If you are asking these questions about GC, then you don't understand how the GC works. Objects which are not reachable count as *free memory* for all practical purposes. That includes all your `String`s.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: OK so until and unless the String objects are stored they will be freed automatically.

Comment: Of course, that's the definition of Automatic Memory Management.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: Thanks.But is there something that can do without creating these objects,if possible.

Comment: @Joe Unless you've got an indexing structure that knows in which positions begin lines, and access the file with a [`RandomAccessFile`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) or similar, you'll have to sequentially read all the file looking for line terminators. That means creating in-memory objects (be it a `String`, be it a `char` or a `byte[]`) to hold file contents while you read them and look for line terminators.

Comment: @XaviLópez If OP calls `read(char[])`, he will be creating zero garbage in the loop.

Comment: @Marko nitpicking this, and just for curiosity, but - wouldn't the code in `read(char[])` be allocating new `char`s all the way? Also true that it wouldn't be _the OP_ creating them.

Comment: @XaviLópez Come on, *allocating a primitive value*?

Comment: You can either spend a lot of time addressing a problem you don't know you have, or you can implement a simple solution, test it and see how it performs, and then put more effort in later if you end up with performance issues when you move to bigger files. Personally I think the latter is a better approach.

Answer (score 2):

Lets assume that the text file has variable length lines, and that you haven't preprocessed it to create an index.  (Otherwise, it should be possible to predetermine the position of the Nth line, and then "seek" to it.)

First observation is that (with the above assumptions), it is not possible to find the Nth line without examining every character before the start of the Nth line.

But you can still do this in a way that doesn't generate lots of garbage.  Here's a simple version:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
for (int i = 1; i < LIMIT; i++) {
     while ((ch = br.read()) != '\n') {
         if (ch == -1) {
             // reached the end of file too soon ...
             throw new IOException("The file has < " + LIMIT + " lines");
         }
     }
}
line = br.readLine();
```

The trick is to skip over the lines without forming them into `String` objects.

Now there is a small flaw in the above.  It is assuming that the lines of the text file are terminated by a newline character (`'\n'`), whereas the `readLine` can cope with 3 kinds of line separator.  But that could be addressed ... without generating extra garbage.  I'll leave it as "an exercise for the reader", along with investigating tweaks like using `read(char[])` instead of `read()`.

You could probably get better performance if you opened the file using a `FileInputStream`, obtained the `FileChannel`, read the bytes into a `ByteBuffer` and then searched it for `(byte) '\n'`.  But the code is significantly more complicated.

---

However, I'd like to reinforce a point made in the comments.  You are *probably* wasting your time with this.  The chances are that your original version runs fast enough for your purposes, despite generating lots of garbage.  In reality, GC is fast when the ratio of garbage to non-garbage is high.  And for a program that reads an discards lines, you are pretty much guaranteed that will be the case.

Rather than spending time figuring out how to make your program fast based on a false premise, you would be better of writing a simple version and measuring its performance on typical input files.  Only optimize if the program is *actually* too slow.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reading strings, you can read data in blocks (may be 1024 bytes block) and search line characters. To read block of data, you can use `byte` array, so it will be reused and so no memory issues. You have to take care of:

- Handling of both `\r` and `\n` characters
- Encoding of the file (like Unicode or other)

Reading data in blocks instead of byte by byte will be more efficient.

Answer (score -2):

I think this should help :

```
FileReader fr = new FileReader("file1.txt");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

LineIterator it = IOUtils.lineIterator(br);
 for (int l = 0; it.hasNext(); l++) {
  String line = (String) it.next();
   if (l == LIMIT) {
      return line;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain how this might be faster ?

Comment: This doesn't answer any of OP's concerns. It allocates all the strings, just as his current code.

Comment: Surely it doesn’t solve anything, but hey: it added a 3rd party library dependency. So it *must* be better than the plain Java code…

Comment: @Holger That's about the same reasoning in the first answer. Two answers over three. So there might be something there...